# LISP Printing to Same Line

Tags: recursion, printing, io, lisp, common-lisp

Another LISP question, I am currently trying to write a function that will return a triangle, whose size will depend on the input of the user

ex: 7

```
aaaaaaa 
aaaaaa 
aaaaa 
aaaa 
aaa 
aa 
a
```

ex: -3

```
aaa 
 aa 
  a
```

I have the code for the positive integer part written, the logic at least, but I've run into a hurdle. I can't seem to have the loop print the letter on the same line. Every time the loop iterates, it goes to the next line. Is there any way to fix this? Also any comments/suggestions on my implementation would be greatly appreciated, I am very new at Lisp. Thanks a bunch everyone! You will find my code below

```
(defun triangle (k) 
    (if (or (= k 1) (= k -1))
        (print 'a)) 
        (if (> k 0) 
           (loop for n from 0 to k
                 do (print 'a)) 
                (triangle (- k 1))))

        
(print (triangle 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `print` prints a newline. `princ` does not.

To further control how you print stuff, there is `format`. It works with directives that start with `~`. Thus, `~a` (or `~A`) prints the object given as argument æsthetically. `~&` prints a newline.

```
(format t "~a~&" 'a)
```

`t` is for `*standard-output*`.

See https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html#structure-of-format

This link also explains how to align strings to the right or to the left, which you might need (if you go the format route).

You can make your code shorter. There is `make-string count :initial-element character` that can replace the loop. A character is written `#\a`.

Also you could call triangle recursively only if k is > 0 (`zerop`). With this and `(format t "~a~&" (make-string k :initial-element #\a))`, my version has only one call to the print function and less "if" machinery:

```
(defun my-triangle (k)
   (format t "~a~&" (make-string k :initial-element #\a))
   (unless (zerop k)
     (my-triangle (decf k))))
```

Comment: could you share how to implement the above call in one line like you mentioned? I am not certain how to fit that part into my code, also just another question, the princ is working perfectly, however my recursive call does not seem to work for whatever reason. It is either not skipping to the next line or printing a space between some of the outputs,

Comment: ex) (print(triangle1)) output-> A AA, (print(triangle(2)) output-> AAA

Comment: OK I added my snippet.